# Broadcast receiver for open application -- Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I referred quit long, is there any broadCast receiver for any of application get starts. I want to notify my application if any other application get starts. I found android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED, but this action will perform once the application restarted again. Pl suggest me if any solution available

Comment: Most of the mechanisms that are referred to in the linked question do not work anymore on the latest releases of Android. Android has been consistently tightening security to prevent this kind of "spying". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> is there any broadCast receiver for any of application get starts

No.

Comment: Thanks. i am not sure, is there any workaround for this.